# How to extract string from the below pattern

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file which contains below details and it's repeats multiple times. I want to extract the Countryid and History value from below text file

The output should be like

```
Countryid: 0115 History: 20220621
```

Could you please help how can I extract above string from this text file using Unix script.

```
{
            "Music": "1410",
            "Countryid": "0115",
            "History": "20220621",
            "Legend": "/api/legacysbo/bondue",
            "Sorting": "/api/dmplus/test",
            "Nick": "hinduja",
            "Scenario": [
                "K",
                "A",
                "S",
                "F",
                "D"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Music": "1466",
            "Countryid": "1312",
            "History": "20221012",
            "Legend": "/api/legacysbo/grenob",
            "Sorting": "/api/dmplus/prod",
            "Nick": "Grenoble",
            "Scenario": [
                "K",
                "A",
                "S",
                "F",
                "D"
            ]
        },
```

Comment: What's the criteria for knowing that the output should be `Countryid: 0115 History: 20220621` rather than `Countryid: 1312 History: 20221012` or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:

- OP wants to print *all* `Countryid/History` pairs
- the `Countryid` entry may come before or after `History` entry
- each `Countryid` entry must have a matching `History` entry
- all sets have a `Music` entry that comes before the `Countryid/History` entries

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -F '"' '

function print_pair() {
    if (countryid && history)                                      # if both variables are non-empty then ...
       printf "Countryid: %s History: %s\n", countryid, history

    countryid=history=""                                           # reset variables
}

$2 == "Music"     { print_pair() }                                 # print previous pair to stdout
$2 == "Countryid" { countryid=$4 }
$2 == "History"   { history=$4   }
END               { print_pair() }                                 # print last pair to stdout
' input.dat
```

If we can assume that `Countryid` always comes before `History` then we can reduce the code to:

```
awk -F '"' '
$2 == "Countryid" { countryid=$4 }
$2 == "History"   { printf "Countryid: %s History: %s\n", countryid, $4 }
' input.dat
```

Both of these generate:

```
Countryid: 0115 History: 20220621
Countryid: 1312 History: 20221012
```

Comment: That for sharing this command.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what does this command will  do - $2 == "Countryid" { countryid=$4 }

Comment: `-F '"'` says to designate a `"` as the input field delimiter; `$2` then refers to the 2nd `"`-delimited field in the line; `$2 == "Countryid"` is a comparison that returns true if the 2nd `"`-delimited field is equal to the string `Countryid`

Answer (score 2):

If this is valid json, one solution is to use a proper json parsing tool, such as [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), e.g.

```
cat test.json
[{
    "Music": "1410",
    "Countryid": "0115",
    "History": "20220621",
    "Legend": "/api/legacysbo/bondue",
    "Sorting": "/api/dmplus/test",
    "Nick": "hinduja",
    "Scenario": ["K", "A", "S", "F", "D"]
}, {
    "Music": "1466",
    "Countryid": "1312",
    "History": "20221012",
    "Legend": "/api/legacysbo/grenob",
    "Sorting": "/api/dmplus/prod",
    "Nick": "Grenoble",
    "Scenario": ["K", "A", "S", "F", "D"]
}]

jq -r '.[] | "Countryid: \(.Countryid) History: \(.History)"' < test.json
Countryid: 0115 History: 20220621
Countryid: 1312 History: 20221012
```

Comment: No I wanted to use Unix script or command to extract those two values..coul you please advise how to do that please

Comment: That IS a Unix script. If that's not what you want (maybe you only want to use mandatory POSIX tools, idk?) then please edit your question to clarify your requirements.